# Meeting was rescheduled but I didn't receive an invite

Tags: professionalism, meetings, email-etiquette

A meeting needed to be rescheduled due to someone not being able to make it. There was discussion of a specific time, as if an invite was to be sent out. I didn't receive it. It could be an oversight that I wasn't sent an invitation, it could be for other reasons, or it may not have been sent at all.

Is it proper etiquette to ask one of my colleagues to forward the meeting invitation to me? I work in the U.S., and this is a work-related meeting, of course.

EDIT:  It turned out to be an Outlook issue, but I think the question and answers have some value, so I am not deleting this now.

Comment: See also my comment on answer below, if interested.  I think the answer below has value, so I am not deleting the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I would ask the organizer if an invite was sent out. And, if so, mention that you did not receive it.

Comment: It turned out our email program, Microsoft Outlook silently updated my calendar and deleted the invitation as it felt I already accepted (unless I deleted it by mistake).  My colleague was open to forwarding the invite to me before I found this all out.  I didn't (in this instance) want to contact the organizer directly, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think this answer has value, so I am not deleting the question.

Comment: But didn't Outlook give you a reminder?

Comment: The meeting was a few days ahead, so I would have received the reminder later.  Side note:  It's important to have your settings such that reminders show on top of other windows, or you could miss them.